# Migration to Spring Batch 5.0 MySQL DataSource not working

Tags: spring, spring-batch, mysql-connector

We had a very simple Spring Batch app working (4.2.1), and writing the Spring Batch Database Schema to a MySQL database where we could see each Job execution details and status.
After trying to migrate to Spring Batch 5.0:
The app is running , but we are not seeing any data written to configured MySQL DB (batch_repo), it seems as if Spring Batch might be using an internal / in memory DB

```
    <parent>   
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>       
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependency>   
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>   
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class MyBatchApplication extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {    
    
    @Override
    protected DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username("root")
                .password("software")
                .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batch_repo?serverTimezone=UTC")
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
                .build();
        return ds;
    }     
    @Bean
    public Tasklet myTasklet() {
        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }    
     @Bean
    public Step myStep(JobRepository jobRepository, Tasklet myTasklet, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        System.out.println(String.format("I am hear!"));
        return new StepBuilder("myStep", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(myTasklet, transactionManager) // or .chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
                .build();
    }        
    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step) {
        return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }     

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyBatchApplication.class, args);
    } }
```

We expected the Spring Batch to use our MySQL database but that did not happen.

Comment: You said you expected it to use "our database". Please [edit] your question to tell us more about what you mean by "our database". Your code is set up to use a database called `batch_repo` in a MySQL server instance running on `mysql://localhost, that is, on the same machine where you run this code. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes that is what we intended but , we do not see any data written in the batch_repo database schema , even though the Spring boot application does run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

> we are not seeing any data written to configured MySQL DB

The app you shared does not write any data to the database. Are you referring to the creation of the schema in the database? This is something that Spring Boot does differently in v3: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes.

Since you are extending `DefaultBatchConfiguration`, you need to create the tables yourself as the Boot auto-configuration (including table creation) will back off.